# How does name resolution work in compound "with" statements?

Tags: delphi, with-statement

Which instance of `Ready` gets tested in the following code, and why?

```
interface

type
  TObject1 = class
  ...
  public
    property Ready: boolean read FReady write FReady;
  end;

  TObject2 = class
  ...
  public
    property Ready: boolean read FReady write FReady;
  end;

implementation

var
  Object1: TObject1;
  Object2: TObject2;

...

procedure test;
var
  Ready: boolean;
begin
  Ready:= true;
  with Object1, Object2 do begin
    if Ready then ShowMessage('which one?');
  end; {with}
end;
```

Comment: The fact that you have to ask this question shows why you shouldn't use **with** in the first place.  It can cause scoping confusion and sometimes lead to hard-to-track-down errors.

Comment: @Mason: 'You' as in 'the OP' or as in 'one'? To me it is obvious that the code above tests `Object2.Ready`. I think you get an intuition for the `with` statement if you use it often. I use it often, and have never seen a bug caused by it...

Comment: It's not my code, I saw in in someone else's code. And was surprised it even compiled. I never use with personally. If I must I use a temporary var to store the stuff into e.g. `tempvar:= Object1.Picture.Bitmap.Canvas; tempvar.Pixels[x,y]:= AColor;` or whatever. The compiler just optimizes the tempvar away and I don't have to worry about these horrible scoping accidents.

Comment: @Andreas: "You" as in "one".  It can even bite you when the code you write is correct.  For example, if you're in a `with` block and you reference a symbol from outside the `with` object's scope, that can break if you update the library the `with` object comes from and it now contains a member with the same name as that outer-scope symbol. (Not hypothetical; I've seen errors caused by this.)  `with` worked a lot better back before OOP was introduced to Pascal than it does now.

Comment: @All *(mostly Andreas)* Thanks for clearing this one up, didn't mean to start a religious war.

Comment: Thank you, @Johan. And I really think it was a wise decision you made to delete your first question on the topic of the `with` construct earlier this night! ;)

Comment: @Andreas, it was a dupe. I noticed too late.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The last one.

```
with Object1, Object2 do
```

is equivalent to

```
with Object1 do
  with Object2 do
```

and so `Object2` will be the number-one priority.

[The official documentation on this matter.](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE/en/Declarations_and_Statements#With_Statements)

Comment: does anybody still use `with`?

Comment: @David: I use `with` a lot, and -- believe it or not -- have never seen a bug caused by it...

Comment: I've seen errors in the past but it is being gradually excised from my codebase

Comment: @Andreas, OK, quick test :-): `with connection, file do
begin
    Close;
end;` What does this code do?

Comment: @Johan: That was a joke, right? :) If not, I have to ask you the types of `file` and `connection`... Also, there are places where `with` is very convenient, and places where it is not...

Comment: file: textfile, connection: TSomeConnection

Comment: @Johan, then your code will not even compile. [Well, for one thing, `file` is a reserved word. But `&file` will not work either, because `textfile` is not a class, object, or record type, and so cannot be used after `with` at all...]

Comment: I have shot myself in the foot with WITH, several times.  Ha. With With.

Comment: @Andreas, yea, `with` is the one area where I wish we had the VB syntax `with connection do .close` so there could be no confusion between the connection.close or some other close outside `with`'s scope.

Comment: @Andreas, you obviously know where I wanted to go with that. But I guess you don't want to play along `with` that :-)

Comment: Names are resolved in nested or compound "with" statements the same as they're resolved from multiple used units. The most recently mentioned unit or object is searched first.

Comment: Johan, your argument doesn't hold. There are exactly the same scoping problems all over pascal code. You don't know whether you're calling a method, or a global procedure, or in which unit it resides. Even xxx.yyy() could be unit xxx.pas and procedure xxx().  The `with` statement is entirely deterministic.  If your code has bugs because of it, the problem was introduced somewhere between your keyboard and your chair.

Comment: @Wouter, it may have been my chair, but it wasn't me sitting in it. And besides the entire computer is deterministic but that doesn't help prevent errors.

Comment: @Rob Kennedy made a very good comment above. It also reminded me of a case where a Delphi programmer considered it a 'bug' that the meaning of `TBitmap` depends on the order of the units `Windows` and `Graphics` in the `uses` clause.

Comment: The `with` statement is a foot cannon, although it's not as bad as threads or pointer math.  Sometimes it just provides the best solution for a situation. No need to avoid any of those like the plague, as long as you know what you're doing.

Comment: Debugging (in Delphi 7) is a little annoying inside a with block, so I told my team to get rid of them as they're encountered in our codebase. I think it's useful for the original programmer to save some keystrokes, but mostly a pain for subsequent developers on the same codebase. If the debugger could keep up, I wouldn't mind so much. Not sure if there are any fixes (or later versions of Delphi) that fix the debugging behaviour inside a with block.

Comment: @Wouter - please show us a case where use of 'with' provides a 'solution' for a problem besides that of programmer laziness. We have cut and paste-it's not hard to qualify your names. I 'know what I'm doing' but that doesn't make me immune to mistakes. Maybe you're different... or you're one of those (lucky??) people who never has to give code to someone else.... At the moment I'm working on an inherited project where the original programmer was obsesssed with 'with' and multiple withs within withs... If he ever meets up WITH me he'll get an earful...

Comment: @David: NO! **Nobody** uses it any more!

Comment: I've seen problems but with, and still use it. The problems were all with excessive, not modest use. One doesn't stop using units either because somebody once USES 100 units

Comment: @Marco I'd stop using units if I could. It's a horrible, blunt tool. You use one of the standard RTL/VCL units to get at one function/class, and everything is puked all over your namespace.

Comment: So? What do you want then? ACL lists per identifier ?